# Uploaded the apk to google but it gave ne errors

Tags: android, eclipse, publish

I did the Signing and Zipalign from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ReRCJgS-g9o .. when I tried publish it, it gave me the following errors or I don't know what they're called (they were in red)

- You need to acknowledge that this application meets the Content Guidelines.
- You need to acknowledge that this application complies with US export laws.
- You need to target at least one country.
- You need to make your application free or set a price for it.

Does anyone knows?

Comment: you have to fill lots of details there, scroll up and down

Comment: Where exactly?  ....

Comment: everything, explore the site. you need to enter all that stuff, http://postimg.org/image/xd0v8v4pl/

Comment: So I don't have to go back to eclipse, I can change these from google store website .. I'll go tomorrow to the laptop that has my google account, I don't have it here with me, thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make your application free or set a price for it while uploading and add country names to target them into those countries...and also check that your app complies with US export laws or not....just fix these little issues and you will be done

Comment: That's when the apk is loaded and I look/fix everything inside?

Comment: No make above changes that i listed while uploading it to play store....you will find options for adding price for your app and other options there...just check them

Comment: That's a new input for me, I'll tell you when I find them, thank you :)

Comment: Hello, I didn't know where or where shall I go, can you give me a URL or tell me where to go?

Comment: sorry for replying sooooo late